# Can I have more than 4 Vacancies appear on the Dashboard in CiviHR?

Tags: civicase, 4.5, civihr, drupal-7

Using CiviHR, can I set the Vacancy Dashboard to show more than 4 Open Vacancies?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. I peeked into [CRM_HRRecruitment_BAO_HRVacancy:getVacanciesByStatus()](https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/master/hrrecruitment/CRM/HRRecruitment/BAO/HRVacancy.php). It's hard-coded to return the four most recently created vacancies.